# Concatenating an address in SSRS

Tags: ssrs-2008-r2

any advice appreciated please.

I have an expression to put an address in a report:

=fields!address1.value & ", " & fields!address2.value &", " & fields!address3

However this returns:

1, Smith Street , Anytown

I would like it to read:

1, Smith Street, Anytown

I would be be very grateful if you're able to suggest the right expression to achieve this - thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Solved via: =Ltrim(Rtrim(fields!address1.value)) & ", " & Ltrim(Rtrim(fields!address2.value)) &", " & Ltrim(Rtrim(fields!address3))